# Identify these Gregorian Chant samples from Delerium's "Flatlands" and "Metaphor"

Tags: identify-this-sample

On Delerium’s [*Semantic Spaces*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Spaces) album, there are a few songs that use samples of Gregorian chants.

I'd like to identify the following samples, so that I can find and listen to the full Gregorian chant songs:

*Flatlands*:

- [00:00-00:35](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZN3twzZIjc)

*Metaphor*:

- [1:16-1:35](https://youtu.be/SKk88dKtRAo?t=1m16s)
- [2:33-2:52](https://youtu.be/SKk88dKtRAo?t=2m33s)

I don't know Latin though, so I'm at a loss as to how to identify those Gregorian chants. Does anyone know what Gregorian chant pieces/songs the samples are from?

Comment: you can check this list of samples although there's no specific mention of the three samples at this time: http://www.enigma-music.com/reviews/delerium/semantic-spaces

Comment: Notwithstanding the answer already given ("B. Monks of S. D. de S.), I think this is a really hard question to answer if you go off of just the aural evidence (i.e., you'd have to resort to interviews, album liner notes, etc.).  The reasons why:
* samples very short
* samples very muffled; makes it hard to catch the latin, because you hear mostly vowels, few consonants
* samples aren't necessarily continuous or even from the same chant
* most gregorian chant groups sound pretty similar
* most gregorian chant songs/melodies sound _very_ similar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't tell you the recordings or performers, but I recognize the chants.

The first is the incipit (beginning) of the [Introit *Roráte caeli de super*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjDIp7oIg5o), "Drop down, ye heavens, from above" (Isaiah 45:8), sung during the pre-Christmas season.

The second sounds like a mash of two samples. I can't make out the first ("oooh"), but the second ("aaah") is a clip from the opening word of the [Offertory *Ave María*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9b0Wmoi2Tk), "Hail, Mary". (Luke 1:28).

The third is from the [Offertory *De profúndis*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OAEeQDVT68A), sung in the requiem mass for the dead: "De profúndis **clamávi ad te**, Dómine", "Out of the depths have I cried unto Thee, O Lord." (Psalm 129:1 Septuagint / Psalm 130:1 Hebrew)

Comment: Great answer, thank you! For the first sample, I had an easier time hearing it in this recording of [Introitus: Rorate coeli](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5W3Q-x3FGo). For the third sample, I had an easier time hearing it in this recording of [De profundis](https://youtu.be/gsxm6SKRjx4?t=7s) after speeding it up.